# Error al desplegar Flask en Apache, Ubuntu 18.04 junto a Wordpress

Tags: python, flask, aws

Soy muy nuevo en aplicaciones Flask, es la primera que estoy desplegando, y honestamente estoy muy perdido.

Todos los tutoriales y/o documentaciones te enseñan a instalarlo omitiendo si existe más páginas o no.

Cuando cambio los virtual host se me cae la página Wordpress y la aplicación flask no funciona.

Tengo Wordpress en:
**/var/www/html**

Tengo mi app flask en:
**/var/www/html/facial**

En facial tengo:
static/
templates/
main.py
run.wsgi

En run.wsgi tengo:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/facial/')
from main import app as application
```

En main.py tengo al principio (no coloco todo el codigo porque funciona bien en local):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Al final:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000, debug = True)
    app.run(debug = True)
```

(Nota: main.py corre bien en local)

Trato de colocar en virtual host desde **sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

Por default tiene:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Con ese ultimo funciona todo bien, lo que hice fue agregarle lo sigueinte (debajo, sin borrar nada).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName MI-IP-ESTATICA
        ServerAdmin admin@localhost
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/facial/run.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/facial/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /var/www/html/facial/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/facial/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Cuando agrego eso ultimo se cae todo y sale el error de **Internal Server Error**

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Nota: quiero aclarar que mi IP es estatica en AWS, tengo mi Wordpress corriendo bien. En la carpeta "facial" de esa IP es que quiero colocar mi app.

¿Cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en tu server Wordpress está ejecutándose en el puerto 80 y en la raíz (/) necesitas crear 1 única entrada de VirtualHost.

Los dos cambios respecto a tu definición de VirtualHost son:

- Tu aplicación en Flask no puede ejecutarse en la raíz, necesitas un path en tu url. Por ejemplo: **/app**
- A su vez, la parte estática dependerá de la ruta a tu app. Por ejemplo: **/app/static**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName MI-IP-ESTATICA
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/html/facial/run.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/facial/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        Alias /app/static /var/www/html/facial/static
        <Directory /var/www/html/facial/static/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Funciona con app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port = 5000, debug = True) MIL GRACIAS.

Comment: Mi otra pregunta es: como hago que siempre se mantenga corriendo?

Comment: Siempre que tengas Apache funcionando debería la app en flask funcionar también.  Esta línea ```WSGIScriptAlias /app /var/www/html/facial/run.wsgi``` lo que hace es llamar a la app en flask. Cada petición que se recibe a través de /app hace que se invoque a la app en flask.